# Apply "where" query to the last few active records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

For my Rails app, I want to do a query for the last 20 Comments added to the app.  I noticed that I can't do something like

```
Comment.last(20).where("length(body) > 20")
```

because I get the error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x007f90e41320c8>
```

But I don't want to query all Comments for those whose length meets my criterion before pulling the last 20 (since there are hundreds of records, and this seems inefficient).

One way I can imagine getting around this is write a loop, but I was wondering if there was a simple, one-line way for me to apply a query to a limited number of active records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`where` is not implemented on an array. But there are methods like: `find` or `select`.

```
Comment.last(20).select { |comment| comment.body.length > 20 }
```